# Generate a dropdown with woocommerce order numbers to use in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I've been looking everywhere, but I just can't find it.

I'd like to give users a way to ask for a refund, but in order to do this, they need to provide a mandatory order number.  Ideally, this would be in a tab in the My Account page, but it could also be a simple shortcode dropped into a contact form 7 form.

I just can't find any solution, anywhere.

I did find one using Gravity Form, but I'd like to do it without a plugin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify and customize below code to load dynamic orders as your requirements:

**Find here code snippet:**

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_orderno' );
function wpcf7_add_form_tag_orderno() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( array( 'orderno', 'orderno*' ),
        'wpcf7_orderno_form_tag_handler', array()
    );
}
function wpcf7_orderno_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {

    /* get all orders here*/

    /*$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
    'limit'    => -1,
    'status'   => array( 'wc-pending' )
    ));

    // Iterating through each Order with pending status
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $order ) {

        $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'limit'    => -1,
        'status'   => array( 'wc-pending' )
    ) );

    // Iterating through each Order with pending status
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $order ) {

        // Going through each current customer order items
        foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values){
            $product_id = $item_values['product_id']; // product ID

            // Order Item meta data
            $item_meta_data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id );

            // Some output
            echo '<p>Line total for '.wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true ).'</p><br>';
        }
    }*/

    $options = '';
    $options .= '<option>-- select order no ---</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="1">Order #10001</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="2">Order #10002</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="3">Order #10003</option>';

    /* use attributes */
    $atts = array();
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
    $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );
    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
    $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html = sprintf(
        '<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap %1$s">
         <select name="orderno">%2$s</select></span>',
        sanitize_html_class( $tag->name ), $options);
    return $html;
}
```

**Add this shortcode in your contact form 7**

```
[orderno orderno]
```

#### I hope it will be useful for you!

Comment: Hey @CKG! Thanks a LOT for the cue... I ended up finding how to get a list of the order numbers per customer and created a Frankenstein using your code and my code :)

Here's what it looks like:
https://pastebin.com/8UtQYfKh

Comment: See here: https://imgur.com/JEqe7bB, you can add label from contact form 7 body..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, thanks a lot for the cue!

```
    add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_orderno' );

function wpcf7_add_form_tag_orderno() {
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( array( 'orderno', 'orderno*' ),
        'wpcf7_orderno_form_tag_handler', array()
    );
}

function wpcf7_orderno_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query',
    array(
        'numberposts' => $order_count,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    ) ) );

    if ( $customer_orders ) {
        $atts = array();
        $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
        $atts['id'] = $tag->get_id_option();
        $atts['tabindex'] = $tag->get_option( 'tabindex', 'int', true );
        $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
        $atts = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );
        echo '<select name="orderno">';
        echo '<option>'.__( "Numéro de la commande", "sinope" ).'</option>';
        foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
            $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
            $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
            echo '
                <option value="'.$order->get_order_number().'">
                    '.$order->get_order_number().'
                </option>
            ';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I used your code for in a contact form dropdown and it works, but it's showing  the information without line breaks. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!